# Add a dialog to the document root, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

in this [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) the dialog is added to an *#dialog-confirm* element. But I want it to be added just to the body and I do not want any predefined div#dialog-confirm element in my html. So how do I realize that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add div#dialog-confirm dynamicly

```
$(document.documentElement).append('<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the '+
   'recycle bin?"<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; ' +
   'margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and' +
   ' cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p></div>');

$( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog();
```

Comment: thanks that works for me, but it does not look like the jquery dialog, it has nearly no css formating

Comment: Did you add UI stylesheet `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

Comment: I add href="/js/jquery/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css", seems to be correct

Comment: I've added a screenshot above

Comment: see this `http://jcubic.pl/test.html` it's seem look fine. The dialog has Gray style, has title bar and icon.

Comment: ok looks just like mine but the font and the buttons are very big

Comment: @artworkadシ SO ping me on this, you'll need to set base font because everything in jQuery UI is relative. `body { font-size: 12px; }`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `$('body')` to enclose the document body object in a jQuery wrapper, and act on that.